# Angular Material icon button formatting

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

This question has a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-dome8b); Given the following [Angular Material button](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview)

```html
<button md-button>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <md-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</md-icon>
</button>
```

How can I increase the gap between `Foo` and the icon (see below):

[image]

I thought this would be easy but Angular Material wraps the contents in `<span class="mat-button-wrapper">` so the final markup is more like:

```html
<button>
  <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
    <span>Foo</span>
    <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
  </span>
</button>
```

So far I've got as far as adding the following CSS to make the wrapper fill the available space but I can't see how to progress:

```
.mat-button-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: solution given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.mat-button-wrapper > span {
  margin-right: 2em;
}
```

Stackblitz :-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-6z4j4m

Comment: This worked but I had to add it to the application wide `style.scss` rather than the component stylesheet.

Comment: then the top one will work. no need to use :host as in stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

```
button md-icon {
  margin-left: 64px;
}
```

This is more semantically appropriate.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-yvqvhm